# How to draw a triangle in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I’d need to sketch this triangle and labels in LaTeX. I’ve tried to look at some codes but I’m still an amateur and I don’t know how to readapt them to my case.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: start by reading the `tikz` package documentation.

Comment: Maybe `pstricks` documentations will be shorter to read… You might take a look at `pst-eucl`

Comment: The `tkz-euclide` package is specially designed for this sort of drawing.

Comment: Starting point: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/geometry/

Answer (score 3):

[image]

There are many ways to draw such pictures in modern LaTeX distributions like TeXLive.
This one uses [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/):

```
// tri.asy
//
// run 
// asy tri.asy
// to get tri.pdf vector image
//

settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph;
import markers;
size(9cm);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"
+"\usepackage{amsmath}"
+"\usepackage{amsfonts}"
+"\usepackage{amssymb}"
);

pen linePen=darkblue+ 0.7bp;
pen dashPen=gray(0.3)+0.7bp+linetype(new real[]{5,5})+linecap(0);

real a=60, b=40;
real alpha=30, beta=18;
pair A=(0,b), B=(a,0), C=(0,0), D;

D=extension(
  A,A+rotate(alpha)*(C-A),
  B,B+rotate(-beta)*(C-B)
);

draw(A--B--C--cycle,linePen);

draw(A--D,dashPen);
draw(B--D,dashPen);
draw(C--D,dashPen);

dot(A--B--C--D,UnFill);

markangle(Label("$\alpha$",Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-15,D,A,C,p=linePen+0.6bp);
markangle(Label("$\beta$", Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-30,C,B,D,p=linePen+0.6bp);
markangle(Label("$\phi$",  Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-10,D,C,B,p=linePen+0.6bp);

label("$A(0,b)$",A,plain.NW);
label("$B(a,0)$",B,plain.SE);
label("$C(0,0)$",C,plain.SW);
label("$D(x,y)$",D,plain.NE);
```

This code uses given values `a,b,alpha,beta`
and function `extension(...)` to find the coordinates `D(x,y)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you just copy and paste it in a LaTeX file or do you have to use a  \usepackage command?

Comment: @user157226:
The simplest way to get a standalone pdf image would be
to save the code in a text file, say, tri.asy and then run `asy tri.asy`.
There are other options to embed the asy files directly in tex files,
if this is really needed, check out the asy docs and/or this site for more info.